# how i can redirect server url when file change?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im trying to uses this function but  only print a message in console not redirect  the actual url of my server when file is changed

```
 watcher.add("/home/diegonode/Desktop/ExpressCart-master/routes/2.mk");


 watcher.on('change', function (info) {
  console.log(info);
router.get('*',function(req,res){  
    res.redirect('http://www.google.com'+req.url)
  })

 });
```

please help me

Comment: if you don't want to send a redirect just remove the `router.get(...` call

Comment: but res redirect not works without router

Comment: how i can get works res redirect without router ?

Comment: i obtain message res redirect is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the user who is on your page to get redirected when the file changes on the server then you will not be able to do that using only server-side code. You need to send a message to the client, using e.g. WebSocket, Socket.io, long polling etc. and the client needs to react to that message and do the actual redirection (i.e. navigate to some URL).